# Different if statements Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have some questions in which I would like to ask.

First off:

```
int id = 1;
```

So, we can have:

```
if (id == 1)
{
//TODO:
}
```

But we can also have:

```
if (id == 1)
//TODO
```

I was wondering what's the difference between these two?

Comment: Try to write two print statements for both snippet and see what it prints.

Comment: in first 1st one you can right multiple lines and in 2nd one you can only write one line then after if block is completed

Answer (score 1):

In the second if statement only first statement after `if` is inside `if` block. In the first if statement you can put as many statements as you like between `{` and `}` and all of them are inside `if` block.

Comment: Well, only the first *statement*. It could be on the same line as the `if` statement condition, or it could be spread over multiple lines. If there are multiple statements on a *single* line, it would still only cover the first of those statements. Lines are a red-herring here.

Comment: That's true it should be statement instead of line, thanks.